# iOS data loss after update

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults

My problem is that I have experienced data loss from NSUserDefaults and from Core Data after updating application. I that possible because of wrong path to NSDocumentsDirectory. Right now current path is acquired this way

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
```

or should it be done this way

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[paths lastObject]];
```

Comment: You only get one path back in both cases so there is no difference. Your data loss comes from something else.

Comment: i think your problem arises due to you create new path every time. you need to make single path every time then definitely data not loss.

Comment: @NamoNamo Do we get different paths every time we call NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling NSUserdefaults "synchronise" method and similary CoreDataContext "save" ?

Since the app is being updated the unsaved changes will be lost.

Comment: Yes, of course I do that. The problem is after updating application from AppStore. It this most likely that app path was been changed after update?

Comment: Yes, App path will be changed after each update. See below -Files Saved During App Updates

When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

    <Application_Home>/Documents

    <Application_Home>/Library

Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely on them being present after an update.

Comment: Link - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

Comment: Thank you. So are you suggesting that I should use this code to get access to NSDocumentsDirectory? NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[paths lastObject]];